Help me build surge protector
I have following parts.  I want to build surge protector for 220v ac lines for whole house with a magnet condactor. What is circuit?
GDT 3RM470M x3
MOVs 20D241K x6, 20D471K x4, 20D431K x4
TVS diode BIDIRECT 1.5KE500CA x2
and Some glass fuses
If need another part tell me.  But just i can change movs
On internet circuits are different in some of them gdt and mov are in series but in this model clamp voltage will increase i want clamp be 470 volt. I'm confused/
Is my circuit ok?


A circuit breaker switch is more useful than a fuse

it is not matter just for schematics

What surge rating is required (as per IEC 61000-4-5)? Or, maybe you mean something else?

These are all good lightning voltage limiters and the necessary fuse is the current limiter.  If there was no fuse, the gas tube would vaporize a large crater on a PCB from follow-on grid current.  The MOV/TVS react in nanoseconds while gas tube takes almost 1kV to short out or ionize gas in 1us.  Since your requirements are not specified, no answer is good enuf

Why are you trying to build one yourself? It doesn't make much sense. Surge protectors, to be of any use, have to be evaluated for their surge absorption capacity. That requires know-how and/or rather special instrumentation to measure, observing safety precautions because some of the tests are destructive.
Throwing together some parts without understanding is just about the worst thing to do. Get an off-the-shelf surge protector.

On internet circuits are different

You can look online to get inspiration, but ultimately the design work and testing is on you. You don't need formal education, but we have no idea what you know, and if we start telling you advice that would make sense for say a professional colleague, you may end up hurting yourself and/or your property.
So, the best advice is: don't do this.
